# Consuming .net wcf rest service via reflection

Tags: c#, rest, wcf-client

I am trying to consume a wcf rest service via reflection if possible. Take a look at the code below:

```
    public static object WCFRestClient<T>(string method, string uri, params object[] args)
    {        
        object o;
        object ret;
        using (ChannelFactory<T> cf = new ChannelFactory<T>(new WebHttpBinding(), uri))
        {                
            T contract = cf.CreateChannel();
            ret = contract.GetType().GetMethod(method).Invoke(o, args);

        }
        return ret;
    }
```

As you see it is a generic method that takes T at run time... my trouble is, I am not sure if I can really reflect on the channel object I am creating above.... Lets say I do, then the trouble starts when I want to create an object instance... Since I can't create an object instance from an interface...

I would also be happy to hear about if there is any other way to accomplish this?  But I prefer to use channel mechanism if I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, creating a `ChannelFactory` for every operation is expensive.  You should avoid that if possible.  The `using` pattern is also problematic for `ICommunicationObject` types in WCF, since `Dispose()` generally corresponds to `Close()` which is a blocking/exception-throwing call.  You will want to call `Close()` explicitly instead and handle `TimeoutException` and `CommunicationException`.

Aside from that, your approach would work.  If you use `ChannelFactory<T>.CreateChannel`, it will create a transparent proxy object of type `T` which could be called upon via reflection if you want.  So you won't have to worry about creating an object from the contract interface -- WCF already does that.

In your code sample, make sure to replace the `o` with `contract` and you should get the results you expect.

Comment: Ive tried your approach but now I am getting the error

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->  System.InvalidOperationException: Manual addressing is enabled on this factory, so all messages sent must be pre-addressed..

Comment: I think you need to add the WebHttpBehavior to your factory:

    factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());